# Removing a Linear Layout which is created on RunTime

Tags: android, android-layout

I am a Beginner in Android, I don't Know how to remove a linear layout which is created on run time... can anyone help me...?

Comment: getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView().findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_id).removeView();

Comment: FYI, you were most likely downvoted b/c your question doesn't include a code snippet of exactly what your trying to achieve. In general, try to be specific as possible and always include some code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can hide the LinearLayout instead of removing it:

```
LinearLayout Line = (LinearLayout) theActiv.findViewById(R.id.lline);
Line.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

and then the linearlayout will no longer be visible.

Answer (score 1):

You can  the [`removeView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeView%28android.view.View%29) method from within the `LinearLayout`'s parent `View`.

Or, if you just want to hide the `LinearLayout` you can do something like `myLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);`.

Comment: View.INVISIBLE if you want the space the view occupies to remain.